# App launch and focus recovery

Tags: c#, kinect

Im working on a kinect app (app A), where I want to launch another local kinect application (app B).

I can launch the app B no problem, and it shows up over my kinect launch app and life is good.    To close app B there is a kinect gesture I have to nuke it.

What Im not sure about is that I want app A to know when app B has gone away, and for app A to grab some event so that it can go fullscreen again and reconnect with the kinect sensor.

I know how to do everything except detect from app A when there is nothing on top of it and it can take control again.

What do I need to do?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the proper (I think) way to deal with this, I was overcomplicating the issue.  I'm using System.Diagnostics.Process to launch app B from app A- so I have access to that process directly since app A never stops.  I just hook up to the Exited event and then I can have app A do whatever I need it to when app B goes away.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**

Try [WindowFromPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633558%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for the screen point where you know  that 2 windows (that of  App A and that of App B) should intersect. If the handle returned is of App B window or of one of its children, then App A is still running.

**Option 2**

Make an App B send a message to App A upon exiting (use [FindWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to find App A's window handle)

**Option 3**

Use  [EnumWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) once in a while (timer based) to enumerate all top level windows and to find if the App B's window is still there

Comment: One point I didn't make clear enough- app A has no knowledge of app B.  App A needs to just be able to determine if it is the topmost window (for example if the app B on top of it closed).  All apps will be full screen, so no need to check for intersections.  Sorry this wasnt more clear

Comment: So the option 1 is your clear choice. Try to define which window is shown in the center of the screen, for example, and if it is App A's window then obviously App B was closed. Do it on timer.